# Trying to execute use database_name command using dynamic query but not switching database name

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute use Database_name command for switching on the particular database using below dynamic query. Query executed successfully but not switch the database.

```
declare @dbname varchar(50)='Database_name',
        @query nvarchar(200)
set @query='use '+@dbname+''
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works ,but the context will be gone as soon query ends

```
    declare @dbname varchar(50)='model',
            @query nvarchar(200)
    set @query='use '+@dbname+'
select db_name()'
    print @query
    exec (@Query)
```

The above query prints model as database name and context is reverted back..

More details on this here:[Switching between databases with dynamic SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118729/switching-between-databases-with-dynamic-sql)

> Session-level changes made in a sub-process (i.e. EXEC / sp_executesql) go away when that sub-process ends. This covers USE and SET statements as well as any local temporary tables created in that sub-process.

one more way is to change SSMS to results to text option,copy that and execute that